# DB table design - multiple columns vs multiple tables

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have a database with normalized tables and such. I ran into a situation where I needed to make a decision of whether to store information into one table with multiple columns or split them into several tables.

Here's an example.

Option 1)

Table 1) --> PlanId, PeriodId, Value

Table 2) --> PlanId, PeriodId, Value

Option 2)

Combined Table --> PlanId, PeriodId, Value1, Value2

Aside from the fact that option 1 will take up from storage space. What is the downside of using option 1 as opposed to option 2.

Comment: When you google your title at site:stackoverflow.com, in what way do the answers not address your particular situation? PS What is this situation? What constraints is each design subject to? Eg Normally if (Planid, PeriodId) is a candidate/primary key we use one table.

Comment: @philipxy I googled before I asked that question and most of them seemed to deal with normalizing the database which is not the situation I'm faced with here. Yes, both PlanId and PeriodId will be primiary. To give a little more context I'm trying to figure out if the database design should be similar to the user interface or not. If yes then option 1 if not then option 2. But I also wanted to understand in general what are the pros and cons of these two options. If you can point me to some resources that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since you say that a situation can either take one relation or some projections of it, it is about normalization. Please edit your context into your question. Again, what  constraints is each design subject to? If possible, give us each design as views of the other? What is the DDL? An example? Eg If one row with a (Planid, PeriodId) pair is in Table 1, what goes in Combined? Or can that not happen. Please read [ask].